# Why do I get a "variable might not have been initialized" compiler error in my switch block?

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement

I'm encountering "a variable might not have been initialized" error when using switch block.

Here is my code:

```
public static void foo(int month)
{
    String monthString;
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1: monthString = "January";
                break;
        case 2: monthString = "February";
                break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
```

The error:

```
Switch.java:17: error: variable monthString might not have been initialized
        System.out.println (monthString);
```

To my knowledge this error occurs when you try access a variable you have not initialized, but am I not initializing it when I assign it the value in the switch block?

Similarly, even if the month is a compile-time constant, I still receive the same error:

```
public static void foo()
{
    int month = 2;
    String monthString;
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1: monthString = "January";
                break;
        case 2: monthString = "February";
                break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
```

Comment: What if `month` variable is 4 or -1? You should add `default:` section to your switch to handle all other cases (when `month < 1` or `month >3`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `month` isn't `1` or `2` then there is no statement in the execution path that initializes `monthString` before it's referenced.  The compiler won't assume that the `month` variable retains its `2` value, even if `month` is `final`.

The [JLS, Chapter 16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html), talks about "definite assignment" and the conditions under which a variable may be "definitely assigned" before it's referenced.

> Except for the special treatment of the conditional boolean operators &&, ||, and ? : and of boolean-valued constant expressions, the values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis.

The variable `monthString` is not definitely assigned prior to being referenced.

Initialize it before the `switch` block.

```
String monthString = "unrecognized month";
```

Or initialize it in a `default` case in the `switch` statement.

```
default:
    monthString = "unrecognized month";
```

Or throw an exception

```
default:
    throw new RuntimeExpception("unrecognized month " + month);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may works fine.

```
public static void foo(int month)
{
    String monthString;
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1: monthString = "January";
                break;
        case 2: monthString = "February";
                break;
        default:monthString = "Invalid month";
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
```